# Grails how to do multiple search queries

Tags: java, grails

I have this from my controller:

```
def purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.createCriteria().list (params) {      
    if ( params.query) {        
        ilike('requestBy', "%${params.query}%")     
    }
```

Above is a snippet from my list method

It can only do one search by the params requestBy

Then i do this in my gsp

```
<g:form action="listPurchaseRequest" method="GET">
    <g:textField id="search" class="pull-right" name="query" value="${params.query}" placeholder=" Search"/>
</g:form>
```

Now i added a new param of requestNumber

How do i do two or more searches?

Comment: Your question is not clear. Do you want the single form input (name=query) to be used to search multiple fields and the results merged? Or do you want the user to type queries into separate search inputs to each search separately, etc. What is it the user is expected to enter and what do you want the program to provide back to the user?

Comment: @nickdos  Oh. sorry. I want a single form input to be used to search my two params requestBy and requestNumber. I can already output the searches in my list so dont worry about that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll take a guess that you want to use the single param `query` to search against multiple fields in the domain class `PurchaseRequest`. This could be done like:

```
def purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.findAllByRequestByLikeOrRequestNumberLike("%${params.query}%", "%${params.query}%", params)
```

See the [Dynamic Finders section of the Grails docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/single.html#finders).

Answer (score 0):

The other alternative could be nesting ilike for different params of the model using or{}:

```
def users = User.createCriteria().list(params) {
        if (params.query) {
            or {
                ilike("fullName", "%${params.query}%")
                ilike("email", "%${params.query}%")
            }
        }
```